# Android studio kvm permission denied

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-18.04, kvm

I have done the following methods in-order to set the run my app on emulator.

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm
sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm
```

But I get the following error message every time I start the emulator.

[image]

And it gets fixed once I execute the second command.

Is there a way that I can run the emulator without always executing the command?

Answer (score 0):

> Fix /dev/kvm is Not Found and Device Permission Denied Errors on
> Linux/Ubuntu 20.04/19.04

**Solutions to problems encountered when creating new devices, namely /dev/kvm is not found and device permission denied errors on Linux/Ubuntu 20.04/19.04.**

When working with Android SDK and Android Studio to develop mobile apps on your Linux Ubuntu 20.04, you often need to use emulators to test your apps. In this case, you will need to use an AVD (Android Virtual Device) to create a new device, but sometimes, you’ll encouter problems when creating new virtual devices with the /dev/kvm is not found and */dev/kvm device permission denied error messages*.

What’s KVM and How to Enable It?
KVM stands for Kernel-based Virtual Machine and it’s a full virtualization solution for Linux on x86 hardware containing virtualization extensions (Intel VT or AMD-V).

Solving /dev/kvm is not found Error
You need to enable KVM, from the BIOS by pressing F1 key before the system boot. Next, go to the Security tab and enable Intel Virtualization Technology and Intel VT-d Feature. Save the new settings by pressing F10. Finally, exit and restart your computer.

Solving /dev/kvm device permission denied Error
After enabling KVM, you’ll likely have another error message that says /dev/kvm device permission denied

To fix this error. you need to install qemu-kvm and add your username to the kvm group.

Head over to your terminal and run the following command to install qemu-kvm:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm
```

Next, you need to add the user your-username to the kvm group using the following command:

```
sudo adduser username kvm
```

Next, in some cases, you also need to run the following command:

```
sudo chown username /dev/kvm
```

You can get your username using the following command:

```
whoami
```

Now, you can verify if your username is added to kvm group using the following command:

```
grep kvm /etc/group
```

If your user name is added. Finish by restarting your Ubuntu 20 system.

Next, follow the steps to create a new AVD, to start using your Android emulator.